# Share image to flickr

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, flickr, image-gallery

How do I add a "share to flickr" on a specific gallery image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flickr provide [documentation on uploading photos via their API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html)